# how to get average of certain column values in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a beginner so I'm not sure whats wrong here. What im trying to achieve is to check if certain cells in a table (column) has numerical values in them and if they do include them in calculating the average value upon losing focus (blur) so that it would kind of be real time.

I'm not sure if calculation function is wrong itself, or if I'm addressing wrong column maybe or trying to insert calculated value in the wrong way. help would be appreciated.

Here is JSfiddle and the code excerpts:
https://jsfiddle.net/NulisDefo/03rn7ew1/5/

table

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-inverse">
    <thead id = "headings" class = "thead-default">
      <tr>
        <th>Tabelio Nr.</th>
        <th>Vardas</th>
        <th>Pavardė</th>
        <th>Pareigos</th>
        <th>Bazinė alga, €</th>
        <th>Valandinis atlyginimas, €</th>
        <th>Veiksmai</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot class = "thead-default">
      <tr>
        <td colspan = "4">Vidurkis</td>
        <!-- <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td> -->
        <td id = "alga">0</td>
        <td id = "valandinis" colspan = "2">0</td>
        <!-- <td></td> -->
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
        <td>1000</td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
        <td>
          <p class = "btn editbtn"><span class = "fa fa-edit"></span></p>
          <p class = "btn" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><span class = "fa fa-trash"></span></p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
        <td>2000</td>
        <td>blum</td>
        <td>
          <p class = "btn editbtn"><span class = "fa fa-edit"></span></p>
          <p class = "btn" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><span class = "fa fa-trash"></span></p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class = "testas">
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
        <td>5000</td>
        <td>blum</td>
        <td>
          <p class = "btn editbtn"><span class = "fa fa-edit"></span></p>
          <p class = "btn" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><span class = "fa fa-trash"></span></p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

script for calculating and trigger

```
$("table").on("blur", "td", function(){
calculate();
} );

function calculate() {
  var sum = 0;
  var counter = 0 //daliklis
  $('#myTable tbody tr td:nth-child(5)').each(function() {
  // $("table tbody tr td:eq(4)").each(function(){
    if (!isNaN(this.value))
    {
      sum += parseFloat($(this).text());
      counter += 1;
    }
    });
    $("#alga").textContent(sum/counter);
};
```

I should probably mention, that prior existing entries can be edited only after pressing edit button.

EDIT: Ok, so apparently all of the solutions work, but the problem is, that if cell is empty, instead of excluding that part from calculation the returned result is NaN

Comment: Something like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/03rn7ew1/7/ , And maybe event this as an updated version https://jsfiddle.net/15w9t8tg/

Comment: td does not have a value attribute, check text

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen the first fiddle displays some weird behavior for me. second one seems to work great. though ill have to look up what exactly some pieces of code mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `focusout` event.

```
$("table").on("focusout", "tr", function(){ 
 calculate();
});
```

I have updated the code like following.

1. Changed event to `focusout` for `tr`. (Because this event listens change made to the `contenteditable` and in your case `tr` has `contenteditable` not the `td`.
2. Added class `avg` in the
   footer td which will tell that these columns needs average to
   calculate.
3. Considered `avg` class in calculation and also updated the logic a bit.
4. Used jquery's `text()` method to set and get the text of `td`.

Check updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/PrashantShirke/03rn7ew1/14/)

Comment: what is the "debugger" statement for here?

Comment: also, I did'nt really get what u mean about the loop. why looping through specific cells that are included in calculation of sum wrong?

Comment: @NulisDefo `debugger` you can remove, it was added to debug the code. and looping required if you want to show the sum for each column in generic way. If you need it only for the two columns then your current code is ok.

Comment: @ Prashant except for when i change it back to `td` instead of `tr` it doesnt update when i change info on new rows. also. any idea why the average returns NaN if a cell value is left empty?
If function should check for it and exclude those cells

Comment: Yes, it's very helpful. though NaN problem could be simply solved by changing `if (!isNaN($(this).text()))` into this `if (!isNaN(parseFloat($(this).text())))` which i did. I'll have to look into your code more in depth because right now i dont understand how u're calculating both needed collumns at the same time exactly

Answer (score 1):

```js
function deleteRow(r) {
    var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(i);
    };


$("#pridet").on("click", function() {
  $("<tr contenteditable><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>").prependTo("table tbody");
  $("table tbody tr td").last().clone().appendTo("table tbody tr:first");
});


$(".editbtn").click(function () {
          var currentTD = $(this).parents("tr").find("td");

              $.each(currentTD, function () {
                  $(this).prop("contenteditable", true)
              });
      });


$("table").on("blur", "td", function(){
  calculate();
} );


function calculate() {
  var sum = 0;
  var counter = 0 //daliklis
  $('#myTable tbody tr td:nth-child(5)').each(function() {
  // $("table tbody tr td:eq(4)").each(function(){
    if (!isNaN($(this).text()))
    {
      sum += parseFloat($(this).text());
      counter += 1;
    }
    });
    $("#alga").text(sum/counter);
}
calculate();
```

```css
.btn {
  width:10%;
  padding-bottom:0;
  margin-bottom:0;
  border-bottom:0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <button id = "pridet">add</button>
      <table id="myTable" class="table table-inverse">
        <thead id = "headings" class = "thead-default">
          <tr>
            <th>Tabelio Nr.</th>
            <th>Vardas</th>
            <th>Pavardė</th>
            <th>Pareigos</th>
            <th>Bazinė alga, €</th>
            <th>Valandinis atlyginimas, €</th>
            <th>Veiksmai</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot class = "thead-default">
          <tr>
            <td colspan = "4">Average</td>
            <!-- <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td> -->
            <td id = "alga">0</td>
            <td id = "valandinis" colspan = "2">0</td>
            <!-- <td></td> -->
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
            <td>1000</td>
            <td>15.3</td>
            <td>
              <p class = "btn editbtn"><span class = "fa fa-edit"></span></p>
              <p class = "btn" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><span class = "fa fa-trash"></span></p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
            <td>2000</td>
            <td>16.8</td>
            <td>
              <p class = "btn editbtn"><span class = "fa fa-edit"></span></p>
              <p class = "btn" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><span class = "fa fa-trash"></span></p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class = "testas">
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
            <td>5000</td>
            <td>10.2</td>
            <td>
              <p class = "btn editbtn"><span class = "fa fa-edit"></span></p>
              <p class = "btn" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><span class = "fa fa-trash"></span></p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
      </body>
```

`$("#alga").text(sum/counter);` instead of `$("#alga").textContent(sum/counter);`

`textContent` is not a function. Use $.fn.text instead.

Plus you use `this.value`. Which should be `$(this).text()` and you should initially call the `calculate()`  function once:

Answer (score 1):

Your loop was not proper. Checkout the [**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/03rn7ew1/11/)  .Now you just need to decide when to trigger **calculate function** which I think you can handle

```
 function calculate() {
      var sum = 0;
      var counter = 0 //daliklis
      $('#myTable tbody tr').each(function() {
      // $("table tbody tr td:eq(4)").each(function(){
        var a = $(this).children('td:nth-child(5)');
        if (!isNaN(a.text()))
        {
          sum += parseFloat(a.html()); console.log(sum);
          counter += 1;
        }
        });
        $("#alga").text(sum/counter);
    }
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/03rn7ew1/11/)

Comment: what is selector `a` which is not even in qoutes?

Comment: @NulisDefo **a** is a variable , contains the required td element. `var a = $(this).children('td:nth-child(5)');`